# how do you chart multiple variables as line chart using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I need to put multiple variables as a line chart to highcharts. Since the number of variables are very high, I need to be able to grab the data and chart it dynamically.

I have multiple of servers that I need to put the cpu utilization of all of the servers in one chart with different lines. My Data would look something like this from the sql query:

```
ServerName  DateTime           CPU
ServerA     1/2/2013 12:00:00  30
ServerA     1/2/2013 01:00:00  20
ServerA     1/2/2013 02:00:00  50
ServerB     1/2/2013 12:00:00  30
ServerB     1/2/2013 01:00:00  30
ServerB     1/2/2013 02:00:00  5
ServerC     1/2/2013 01:00:00  10
serverC     1/2/2013 02:00:00  50
ServerC     1/2/2013 03:00:00  70
```

I was looking at the below code, but since I cannot see the data, I cannot really make anything out of it. How would I add the result of a sql query as above to the multiple line series chart using highstock charts?

```
$(function() {
    var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        seriesCounter = 0,
        names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],
        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

    $.each(names, function(i, name) {

        $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',   function(data) {

            seriesOptions[i] = {
                name: name,
                data: data
            };

            // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
            // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
            seriesCounter++;

            if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
                createChart();
            }
        });
    });



    // create the chart when all data is loaded
    function createChart() {

        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 4
            },

            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                    }
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 2,
                    color: 'silver'
                }]
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    compare: 'percent'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
                valueDecimals: 2
            },

            series: seriesOptions
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parse your dates "1/2/2013 12:00:00" to JS timestamp (time in milisecods). You can use i.e. Date.UTC() function. Secondly you have to use numbers to display chart (not strings) for CPU values.

Comment: my question was how do you serialize multiple series in one chart? Do u know of a good example? I have to do this programmaticall, need to call extendible to build the charts.

Comment: We have no built-in mechanism to serialize arrays. We use JSON, to configure series / data. So onyl what you need is parse your data to correct format.

Comment: @Sebastion Bochan, I am sorry for all these questions. Do you have an example of how the data needs to be formated and presented to highcharts, for example for 3 different series data?

Comment: series:[{name:'serie1',data:[[Date.UTC(2012,2,2),5],[Date.UTC(2012,2,5),12]]},{name:'serie2',data:[[Date.UTC(2012,2,2),5],[Date.UTC(2012,2,5),12]]},{name:'serie3',data:[[Date.UTC(2012,2,2),5],[Date.UTC(2012,2,5),12]]}]